# Execute sudo command in C with system()

Tags: sudo, root, c

I am writing a piece of C code that will run some `sudo` command in `system("sudo ip route ...")` function call.

This call is being done in a pthread created by the main thread, and the main program is being executed with `sudo ./program` when starting up.

When I run the program, Ubuntu prompts me to enter password for nobody:

`[sudo] password for nobody:`

I also tried to do `system("ip route ...")` straightly but it gives me negative return meaning that it is not executed.

What should I do in the thread to allow the `system()`call to use the `sudo` privilege inherited from the main program?

Comment: [Put down that chocolate-covered `sudo` banana and step away.](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/put-down-the-chocolate-covered-banana.html)  You've buried your **real** question, which is _Why doesn't `system("something")` work when my program is running as the superuser?_  To enable people to answer that, you'll have to actually tell people what command you are trying to run, for starters.

Comment: @JdeBP I have edited, it is a `ip route` command to manipulate routing table.

Comment: @JdeBP While I sort of agree with the sentiment here,  **your article sucks the banana it aims to criticize**.   Using absurdist mixed metaphors is always very cutesy and fun but -- in stark contrast to E. S. Raymond, who's *serious* work you evidently wish to categorize that piece of ___ with -- you obviously do not possess the knowledge or willpower to add anything at all to the pseudo-pithy/"look at me I'm cool" title.   Please desist from splattering your drool over the internet further; if you want to be serious be serious, if you want to be a jackass, do it in private.

Comment: P.S. I believe [here is what you meant to say](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), in the future please just use that.

Comment: What shell is your `/bin/sh`? What happens when as root in a terminal, you launch your `ip route ...` command?

Comment: And, just for fun, what do you get if you call `system("id");` from your program?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to do anything special to inherit the root privileges that `sudo` has given you. Processes generally automatically inherit the privileges of their parents. The reason `system(3)` isn't working is probably either because you're root (see below) or because you're on a thread.

That being said, don't use `system(3)`. This is because `sudo` works by using setuid, and that doesn't play well with `system()`. Therefore, use the `exec(3)` family of functions instead (except for `execlp()` and `execvp()`). See [`man 3 system`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) for more information.

Now, with *that* being said, **don't use `system(3)` *or* `exec(3)`**. Instead, just directly call the C API for manipulating the IP tables. Why would you waste system resources spawning a new process or two, when you could just simplify your program instead? (At this point you're getting to the point where your question belongs on Stack Overflow, though).

Comment: Hmmm.  `system()` doesn't work well with setuid programs, in which the effective UID of the process is the owner of the executable file and the real UID is the original UID of the person who's running it (i.e., they are different).  But, under `sudo` (or `su`), the effective UID and the real UID are the same, so I don't know why that would be a problem.

Comment: @Scott, ah, nevermind. `sudo` works by being a setuid binary, but I guess it changes the real id as well as the effective id before executing anything else.

Comment: The man page doesn't seem to explain why not `execlp` nor `execvp`. What's dangerous about using the PATH searching variants of `exec` to do this? (in my case I have a different setuid program I want to run).

Answer (score 2):

```
system("echo XXXX | sudo -S gedit");
```

Where XXXX your password.

Comment: It does if you specify `-S` (which this answer does).  However, hard-coding your password in a program (or especially a script) is a pretty terrible idea.  And what password should he even user here? `sudo` is asking him for the password for "nobody".  Also, what does `gedit` have to do with this question?

Comment: to expand on why hard-coding your password in a program is a bad idea, one reason is that you've just leaked that password to everyone who can read `/proc/$pid/cmdline` (i.e. everyone).

Comment: It is bad practice to echo passwords. Because any user may see it by using command: `ps -Af | grep echo`