# Entering password into terminal through c

Tags: c, terminal

I searched for this question and could only find python variants. If this is a duplicate apologies upfront.

I'm trying to write a script in c that auto setup systems so that I don't have too manually do it on heaps of computers. For part of the script I need to enter a password.

Comment: It is not the terminal that requires a password but some program you are running.  Some programs just read `stdin` but some use low-level terminal IO to ensure that passwords have to be entered manually.  You will have to look at each program to find which method they use.

Comment: I think you would be better off with an existing single-sign-on tool. You are not asking for such a tool (which would be off-topic), I know. But it would be worth the effort of searching.

Comment: I'm actually looking to input the computer admin password and not a program password. I also would like to know how to detect when bash requires a password

Comment: `bash` does not require a password, but the login process might, or the `sudo` program (which has nothing to do with `bash`).  Under what circumstances are you requiring a password?

Comment: I meant sudo bash

Comment: @F3nrir that is what every one is trying to explain to you. The terminal does not require your password. It is one of the program that actually needs the password and the terminal just takes it from you and passes it on to the program through some "means". If you are trying to execute a command, with `sudo`, then it is the program named `sudo` that is asking for the password.

Comment: @F3nrir You can use `expect`, `sshpass` and few others to deal with these cases. But you really need to know what your program is like Yunnosch and cdrake mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the terminal, why not use bash for these setups? In both instances of C, or bash, if you're accessing high privilege level areas, you'll need privilege access. The thing you'd be looking for would be a sudo command. It'll prompt you for the password prior to running it, and is just ran as follows:

```
sudo someExecutable
```

Comment: I already knew this and I would still like to know how to insert passwords into terminal through c though

Comment: Would this solve your problem?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29456701/execute-sudo-command-in-c-with-system

Answer (score 0):

Some programs (that prompts for password) use `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` call for ensuring that password is typed via terminal.

In that case it not possible use normal pipes for sending password to the program.

For those programs, you can create a pseudo terminal, that is used instead of a pipe. Example:

```
void test(void)
{
    const int fdm = posix_openpt(O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
    if (fdm != -1)
    {
        char name[100];
        unlockpt(fdm);
        ptsname_r(fdm, name, sizeof(name));

        const int fds = open(name, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY);
        if (fds != -1)
        {
            const pid_t child_pid = fork();

            if (child_pid == -1)
            {
                // TODO: Error handling
            }
            else if (child_pid == 0)
            {
                dup2(fds, STDIN_FILENO);
                dup2(fds, STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(fds);
                close(fdm);
                execl("/sbin/program_that_requires_password_from_terminal", "blabla", (char*) NULL);
            }
            else
            {
                const char password[] = "mypassword\n";
                int status;
                close(fds);
                // TODO: wait prompt from the program by reading fdm
                write(fdm, password, strlen(password));
                waitpid(-1, &status, 0);
                close(fdm);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In that way `isatty(STDIN_FILENO)` in the target program returns 'true'.